# Eager fetching nested object with DetachedCriteria in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, detachedcriteria

I have to modify a large Hibernate DetachedCriteria query to fetch some additional associations.

My object graph resembles the structure below, I want to fetch the sales associated with each Car:

```
<class name="Showroom" table="showroom">
    ...
    <bag name="cars" lazy="false">
        <one-to-many class="Car" />
    </bag>
    ...
</class>

<class name="Car" table="car">
    ...
    <set name="sales" lazy="true">
        <one-to-many class="Sale" />
    </set>
    ...
</class>
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Showroom.class);
// ... Existing criteria query code ...
criteria.setFetchMode("cars.sales", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

But the associationPath argument in setFetchMode seems to ignore the dot notation and I get a LazyInitializationException:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role: Car.sales, no session or session was closed

I've search around and so far found no examples or information. The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-dynamicfetching) does not provide examples on how to fetch nested associations, and the [Javadoc for setFetchMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setFetchMode%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.FetchMode%29) seems to suggest that my dot-notation approach should have worked...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ShowRoom.class, "showRoom");
criteria.setFetchMode("showRoom.cars", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("showRoom.cars", "car", CriteriaSPecification.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.setFetchMode("car.sales", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

You can't chain properties in a criteria query. And even in a HQL queries, `cars.sales` is invalid, since `cars` refers to a collection, and not to an instance of Car. A join is necessary to be able to refer to a Car in the collection of cars. That's what the `createAlias()` call does. The above is similar to

```
select showRoom from ShowRoom
left join fetch showRoom.cars car
left join fetch car.sales
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanation. I didn't realise createAlias had a dual purpose of creating joins as well as field aliases.